# Python: index error with numerical differentiation

Tags: python, scipy, data-analysis, numeric

In my code I am extracting the velocity and acceleration from time, position measurements and I am receiving an index error when performing numerical differentiation:

```
    VelocityVsTime = np.empty((2,0), float)

for i in range(1, len(PosVsTime[0])-1):
    velocity = (PosVsTime[1][i+1] - PosVsTime[1][i-1]) / (PosVsTime[0][i+1] - PosVsTime[0][i-1])
    VelocityVsTime = np.append(VelocityVsTime, [[PosVsTime[0][i]], [velocity]], axis = 1)
    
#print(VelocityVsTime)

AccelerationvsTime = np.empty((2,0), float)

for j in range(1, len(VelocityVsTime[1])-1):
    acceleration = (VelocityVsTime[1][i+1] - VelocityVsTime[1][i-1]) / (VelocityVsTime[0][i+1] - VelocityVsTime[0][i-1])
    AccelerationvsTime = np.append(AccelerationvsTime, [VelocityVsTime[0][i]], [acceleration], axis=1)
    
print(AccelerationvsTime)
```

The error is:

```
IndexError: index 50 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 49
```

any tips on how to correct this? Thanks

Comment: If ` i in range(1, len(PosVsTime[0])-1)` then `[i+1]` can reach full `len`. Since Python indexes are zero-based anything like `ar[len(ar)]` will throw an error,

Comment: What is datatype is  `PosVsTime` in the above? Also would be helpful to show a bit more of the error - what line did it occur on?

Comment: The '''PosVsTime''' variable is a 2xN vector with column 0 as time, and column 1 as position, from a CSV

Comment: First step to correcting this is to identify exactly where the error occurs.  That means looking at the traceback (which you forgot to show!).  Within the problem line, look for indexing operations, and in particular look for one where the array has shape like (49,...), and where the index can be as large as 50.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code fails to run.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Answer (score 0):

heres the full code: the error occurs on line 42 where I declare the acceleration variable

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


PosVsTime = np.loadtxt("balldata.txt", delimiter=",").transpose()

#print(PosVsTime[0][0])

#t_0 = PosVsTime[0][0]

#pos_0 = PosVsTime[1][0]


#print("The initial state of this system at time = 0 is ", pos_0)


VelocityVsTime = np.empty((2,0), float)

for i in range(1, len(PosVsTime[0])-1):
    velocity = (PosVsTime[1][i+1] - PosVsTime[1][i-1]) / (PosVsTime[0][i+1] - PosVsTime[0][i-1])
    VelocityVsTime = np.append(VelocityVsTime, [[PosVsTime[0][i]], [velocity]], axis = 1)
    
#print(VelocityVsTime)

#plt.errorbar(VelocityVsTime[0], VelocityVsTime[1], fmt = '--k')

AccelerationvsTime = np.empty((2,0), float)

for j in range(1, len(VelocityVsTime[0])-1):
    #acceleration = (VelocityVsTime[1][i+1] - VelocityVsTime[1][i-1]) / (VelocityVsTime[0][i+1] - VelocityVsTime[0][i-1])
    #AccelerationvsTime = np.append(AccelerationvsTime, [VelocityVsTime[0][i]], [acceleration], axis=1)
    
print(AccelerationvsTime)
```